# Why do I get a "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error when iterating in a pug template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am building something with Node and Express, and if the user is not logged in then the home page is supposed to display signup and login links in the nav bar. Everything looks like it should work, and I am able to display the information if I don't iterate. But when I use iteration I get this error:

```
/home/michael/Desktop/budget-app/views/layout.pug:13 11| a(href='/') Simple Money Manager 12| if authLinks > 13| each val, index in authlinks 14| a(href='' + val) index 15| 16| // Content Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Here is the `render` method:

```js
res.render('home', {
   authLinks: {
      Signup: "/signup",
      Login: "/login"
   }
});
```

Here is the code used in my pug file:

```html
if authLinks
    each val, index in authlinks 
      a(href='' + val) index
```

Why is authLinks undefined? I am at a total loss. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `authLinks` and not `authlinks` in loop

```
if authLinks
    each val, index in authLinks//here 
      a(href='' + val) index
```

**Edit:** your authLinks is an object, not an array and cannot repeat as well:

```
res.render('home', {
   authLinks: [{
      Signup: "/signup",
      Login: "/login"
   }]
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Your answer gives the same error and seems to be the same thing I was doing.

Comment: @MichaelAlexander It isn't; check your line 2 versus their line 2.